# How do I add CORS headers to my c# .NET webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

Screen dump: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZncVT.jpg

How can I add CORS response headers in my C# WebApi / Reactjs project?
I have a workspace with a WebApi in c# and a Reactjs project that communicates using cors.

I have a component called ../Compontents/Games.js -->

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import GameService from '../Services/GameService';

const Games = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        setGames(GameService.getAll);
        console.log(games);
    }, [])

    const [games, setGames] = useState([]);

}

export default Games;
```

Also here you can see my GameService

```
import axios from 'axios';
import IGame from '../Interfaces/IGame';

const GameService = (
    () => {
        const gameEndpoint = 'http://localhost:5137/Game' 

        const getAll = async () => {
            const result = await axios.get(gameEndpoint)
            console.log(result.data)
            return result.data;
        }

        const getById = async (id: number) => {
            const result = await axios.get(`${gameEndpoint}/${id}`)
            console.log(result.data)
            return result.data;
        }

        const getByTitle = async (title: string) => {
            const result = await axios.get(`${gameEndpoint}/${title}`)
            console.log(result.data)
            return result.data;
        }

        const postGame = async (newGame: IGame) => {
            const result = await axios.post(gameEndpoint, newGame)
            console.log(result.data)
        }
        
        const deleteGame = async (id: number) => {
            const result = await axios.delete(`${gameEndpoint}/${id}`)
            console.log(result.data)
        }

        const putGame = async (editedGame: IGame) => {
            const result = await axios.put(gameEndpoint, editedGame)
            console.log(result.data)
        }


        return {getAll, getById, getByTitle, postGame, deleteGame, putGame}
    }
)();

export default GameService;
```

When I try to call the GetAll function from GameService my console fills up with cors errors. (*see the imgur screendump). I realize I need to add CORS response headers, but after hours of searching stackoverflow I only find php stuff and other code I dont understand.

I have looked everywhere in the file structure of both the api and the react website, and I cant find 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' written anywhere in either... Can someone help me make sense of these errors?

Let me know if you need me to post any additional information, as I'm not the most professional user on here :)

Edit (@gunr2171):
from my Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddCors( //add cors
    builder => {
        builder.AddPolicy("AllowAll", //name of convention
            builder => builder
                .AllowAnyHeader()   
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
        );
    }
);

app.UseCors("AllowAll)");
```

Comment: CORS for HTTP Requests is generally added by the _browser_, not by client code. How are you validating CORS on the server side?

Comment: @gunr2171 I dont know if this is what youre askin for but I made an edit for you

Comment: @gunr2171  Not sure what you're talking about at all and it sounds like you've confused CORS with something else.  CORS is dictated by the server and browsers interpret the CORS responses on if they are allowed to use the content.  There is no such thing as "validating CORS on the server side" as servers generally just adds the allowed origin headers to requests irrespective of clients.

Comment: If you comment out the CORS stuff in C# does it get rid of your errors? Also you've got a typo `AllowAll)"` which I'm assuming is a typo when posting up here.

Answer (score -2):

Check if you don't have an error code 500. Sometimes, if your server respond with a 500 error, the browser throws a CORS error, which is not really a CORS error.